# Changing color rectangle inside button wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to achieve something that's driving me nuts, it partially works, but I can't achieve the same results that I did on my old Winforms project(I am trying to learn WPF and move away from Winforms).

I am trying to paint a Button if I place the mouse over it, so it change the background color and add a yellow rectangle on the left like this:

[image: results of winforms project]

I tried to create with much difficulty a Styled button that partially do the job, it changes the background color but I can't figure out how to paint the yellow rectangle

```xml
<Style x:Key="MenuButton" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Button.Background" Value="#525864"/>
    <Setter Property="Button.Foreground" Value="#ffffff" />
    <Setter Property="Button.BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Button.Margin" Value="10,0,0,0"/>
    <Setter Property="Button.Height" Value="40"/>
    <Setter Property="Button.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            **
            <Setter Property="Rectangle.Fill" Value="#f0e68c"/> **
            <Setter Property="Button.Background" Value="#737b8c"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

From the main Window I created the button like this:

```xml
<Button Style="{StaticResource MenuButton}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Width="10"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Comparador Archivos" Margin="5,0,0,0" 
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <Image Grid.Column="2" Margin="5" Source="/Imagenes/icono_comparar.png"/>
    </Grid>
</Button>
```

Comment: Could you describe the details of the task itself?
It is very likely that you have chosen the wrong implementation method.
If your button has two states (on/off), then you need to use ToggleButton.
If you can have only one enabled button from a group of buttons, then you need to use either the RadioButton group or, better, even one ListBox instead of several buttons.

Answer (score 2):

Because the `Content` in the `ContentPresenter` is set on the UI, the style does not know the existence of the `Rectangle`. Therefore, to access the `Rectangle`, you need to insert `<Grid> ~ </Grid>` directly instead of `<ContentPresenter/>`.

And in `Style.Trigger`, objects in the `ControlTemplate` is not accessible.
Therefore, it must be processed within `ControlTemplate.Triggers`.

By giving `x:name` to the `Rectangle`, internal properties can be accessed in `Trigger`.

```
<Style x:Key="MenuButton" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#525864"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ffffff" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,0,0,0"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="rec" Grid.Column="0" Width="10"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Comparador Archivos" Margin="5,0,0,0" 
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <Image Grid.Column="2" Margin="5" Source="/Imagenes/icono_comparar.png"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="rec" Property="Fill" Value="#f0e68c"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#737b8c"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource MenuButton}"/>
```

Comment: I will complement @elena.kim answer.
You need to visually separate the presentation of the Button itself - it is set in the Template property.
And the visual representation of the Button Content - it is set directly by UI elements in Content or, for common CLR types, in ContentTemplate.

Judging by your explanations, the yellow rectangle refers to the visual presentation of the button itself, and the caption and image to Content.

I would divide these three elements into two parts.
But I have an ambiguity about the problem itself, what I wrote about in the comments to the main question.

Comment: @EldHasp Thank you for complementing my lack of explanation!

Comment: thank you! this gave me the right answer and I finally finished the button with a few modifications. now its working properly

Comment: @AndresDiazDeValdes If my answer was helpful, please [accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Cant you just change the fill hex so one of these

`<Setter TargetName="rec" Property="Fill" Value="#f0e68c"/> <Setter Property="Background" Value="#737b8c"/>`
Change the hex of Value="#hexcode"
Tell me if it works

Comment: The @elena.kim answer gave the the light but thanks.